# Oracle Deadlock

Tags: oracle

Does a composite primary key(Foreign key + Primary key) need indexing to avoid deadlock ?

Example scenario: 
One to many relationship(One employee can work in more than one department)

Parent table : 
Employee
1.Employee ID(Primary key)
2.Name

Child table : 
Department (Composite Primary key --> (Idx + Employee ID)
1.Idx(Primary key)
2.Department name
3.Employee ID(Primary key)

class Employee {
int Employee ID;
String name;
List departments;
}

class Department {
String departmentName;
}

```
<list cascade="all,delete-orphan" name="ListOfDepartment" table="Department">
        <key column="Employee ID" />
        <index column="idx"/>
        <composite-element class="Department">
            <property name="departmentName" column="departmentName" not-null="true" />
        </composite-element>
</list>
```

Comment: What are you doing that you think will cause a deadlock?

Comment: In Oracle you will get an index for a primary key regardless. If you don't create it then Oracle will as that is the way it implements the PK constraint. A deadlock is most likely to occur through incorrect design and your table structure seems odd - intuitively I would see the employee as a child of the department and not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

1) A small description of `Deadlock`: It's a situation where two sessions block each other, such that neither can do anything. Deadlocks are detected and resolved automatically by the DIA0 background process.

2) `Deadlocks are not the DBA’s problem`; they are caused by bad program design and resolved automatically by the database itself.

3) They occur because the code attempts to do something that is logically impossible. The well-written code will always request locks in a sequence that cannot cause deadlocks to occur, or will test whether incompatible locks already exist before requesting them.

So, `you do not need` to think about creating an `Index` for your tables just because of `avoiding deadlocks`. It's better to ask your program designers to write a good code.

BUT, if you think that there might be some wrong codes (it's better to fix them) OR you don't want WAITING on `Parent table`, then `CREATE INDEX` for your `FOREIGN KEY COLUMN`, cause if you will not do that you will have `WAITING` for the `Parent table` when some DML process ongoing in `Child table`, try to do this example and you can understand:

```
        CREATE TABLE dept (
        dept_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
        dept_name VARCHAR2(25)
        );

        CREATE TABLE emp (
        emp_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
        emp_name VARCHAR2 (25),
        dept_id NUMBER REFERENCES dept (dept_id)
        );

        INSERT INTO dept VALUES (10, 'IT');
        INSERT INTO dept VALUES (20, 'Market');
        COMMIT;

    SESSION1: INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1, 'Alex', 10);
    SESSION2: DELETE FROM dept WHERE dept_id = 20; --- different dept_id, not the same with SESSION1 data

RESULT: Here you get `THE LOCK`, so `SESSION2 waiting` FOR `SESSION1 COMMIT`;
```

Now, we will `CREATE an INDEX` FOR THE `FK ON emp` TABLE:

```
CREATE INDEX emp_dept_id_idx ON emp (dept_id);
```

try again:

```
SESSION1: INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1, 'Alex', 10);
SESSION2: DELETE FROM dept WHERE dept_id = 20;

RESULT: Now NO WAITING, because the `Parent table` do not need to do `full table` scan and `LOCK whole table`;
```

Book: OCA-OCP 11g All-in-One (Deadlocks);
Details: http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteunindex.html